# Im getting an 1004 error when copying data in excell

Tags: excel

i am trying to copy data from one large excel file to another(6K+ rows).
The goal is to copy 3 seperate columns next to eachother after checking if there is already a column of data present. I want to make a macro that copies the data every day and places it next to the older column of data(with 2 columns in between). The copying data part is working fine but i cant figure out how to make it so there is space in between the copied data.

The error im getting is method of 'range' object '_worksheet' failed.

the code i have is:

```
Function Inc(ByRef i As Integer)
   i = i + 1
End Function

Sub grabData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet


'## Open both workbooks:
Set wb1 = Workbooks("clipDataBaan.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\Data\Documents\dataOpenOrders.xlsm")

Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Data")


'this next piece of code is to determine the last column and add 2 empty spaces in between the next block of columns

Dim lclm As Integer

lclm = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Inc lclm
Inc lclm


'copy the first column:

wb2.Sheets("19-9-2018").Range("A2", wb2.Sheets("19-9-2018").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).Copy

'Now, paste to worksheet:

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, lclm)).PasteSpecial -this is where i get the error

Inc lclm 'step to the next column so data isnt pasted on top of eachother

'repeat for 2 other columns

wb2.Sheets("19-9-2018").Range("N2", wb2.Sheets("19-9-2018").Range("N65536").End(xlUp)).Copy

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, lclm)).PasteSpecial

Inc lclm

wb2.Sheets("19-9-2018").Range("O2", wb2.Sheets("19-9-2018").Range("O65536").End(xlUp)).Copy

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, lclm)).PasteSpecial

wb2.Close

End Sub
```

I know im doing something wrong with selecting the right workbook but i can not for the life of me figure out what.

if i change the paste command to a static value it works like so:

```
ws1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
```

I tried using a range variable and setting the range in that variable and then using that variable in the paste command like so:

```
ws1.Range("RangeVar").PasteSpecial
```

But i was still getting the same error 1004

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not *"selecting the right workbook"*, but referencing the cell correctly.

If you are referencing a *cell* by its row and column number, just use  `Cells` and avoid `Range` entirely.

Change `ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, lclm)` to `ws1.Cells(2, lclm)`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, i thought i read somewhere that paste didn't work on Cells so i didnt look at that option but i read it wrong and paste doesn't work but pastespecial does. it works now!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a range variable (`Dim RangeVar as Range`), then you can call it without the `Range()` wrapped around it:

```
Dim RangeVar as Range
Set RangeVar = ws1.Range("A2")
RangeVar.PasteSpecial
```

Make ***sure*** that everywhere you reference a `Range`, you include the worksheet you expect that to be on.  Otherwise, it's going to reference whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.

Comment: This wouldve worked except i couldnt get my range into the rangevar

Comment: Set selectRng1 = selectRng1.Cells(2, lclm) this didnt work and                               
 Set selectRng1 = Range(Cells(2, lclm)) this didnt either